# How do I get Vim to treat underscores in a string as a word break?

Tags: vim

I would like Vim to treat underscores in a string as word-breaks, just like a spaces.  For example, if I have:

```
sub foo_bar {
    return;
}
```

With the cursor starting at the far left of the first line, (on the 's' of 'sub'), hitting 'w' will place the cursor on the 'f' in 'foo', a second press of 'w' takes me to the curly, and a third hops down to the 'r' of 'return'.  I want that second press of 'w' to take me to the 'b' in 'bar'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install the [camelcasemotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) plugin and see the example near the bottom of the linked page, which shows how to map the <kbd>w</kbd> key to use CamelCase or underscored_words.

Answer (score 34):

`:set iskeyword-=_`

Comment: That doesn't exactly work as the cursor lands in the _ first, and then on the 2nd 'w' press goes to b.

Comment: After having looked around the vim docs and google, I actually don't think there's another way. Perhaps someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: For me this is a "good enough" solution without any dependencies, thanks!

Comment: Not good. After this, ctrl-p and ctrl-n don't work any more for words with underscores.

Comment: To do the opposite in case of an accident, `:set iskeyword+=_`.  Also, `:set iskeyword&` will reset it to its default.

Comment: Additional downside of this solution is the fact, that the code will be syntax highlighted on substring-level (from underscore to underscore). For example, if the language you work in has the keyword "file" defined and you create variable "file_name", the "file" part will be highlighted and the rest not. This can easily get out of control with multiple colors for various keywords.